# LINQ + EntityFunctions in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have such code using EntityFramework Alpha3 (from nuget):

```
class Member
{
    [Key]
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Sitename { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RegDate { get; set; }
}

class MembersContext : DbContext
{
    public MembersContext()
        : base("Name=ConnectionString")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        Database.SetInitializer<MembersContext>(null);
        const int memberKey = 1001;
        using (var db = new MembersContext())
        {
            var query = from m in db.Members
                        where
                            m.Key == memberKey
                            && EntityFunctions.DiffDays(m.RegDate, DateTime.Now) > 0
                        select m;


            var member = query.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

I have tried to use EntityFunctions in fresh ASP.NET MVC project (based on .net 4.5) - it always fails with error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] DiffDays(System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime], System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Same code works completely fine in Console app. Any ideas, what's wrong?

Comment: Try using this: `&& EntityFunctions.DiffDays(m.RegDate.Value, DateTime.Now)` as `m.RegDate` is a nullable property in the class definition.

Comment: The issue is all in the exception - EF is unable to translate your custom method `DiffDays` into executable SQL. Could you post the implementation of `DiffDays`?

Comment: @James, it's not a 'custom method' but part of `Entity Framework` utility functions to construct custom LINQ queries than could be translated into store expressions (SQL)

Comment: @haim770 ah, my mistake. You appear to be on an alpha version of EF...is it possible it just hasn't been updated to support these functions yet?

Comment: @MichalDymel Instead of this `if (query.Any())
            {
                var member = query.First();
            }` use FirstOrDefaul

Comment: @saravanan it doesn't make a difference if it's nullable or not. The function definition from EntityFunctions allows use of nullable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect that in the case of your ASP.NET app, you also have a reference to `System.Data.Entity`, and that you are using the `EntityFunctions` class defined `System.Data.Entity`.

However, Entity Framework 6 has removed the dependency on `System.Data.Entity` and has redefined all necessary classes for that purpose inside of the `EntityFramework` assembly.

Meaning that, in the case of your console app, I am guessing that either by design (`System.Data.Entity` is not referenced) or by accident (`System.Data.Entity` is referenced but the `EntityFunctions` class is taken from `EntityFramework.dll`), the correct version of `EntityFunctions` (from `EntityFramework.dll`) is taken.

If you are using any version of Entity Framework 6, make sure that you are using the `EntityFunctions` class that can be found in `EntityFramework.dll`, not the one in `System.Data.Entity`. [Source code of `EntityFunctions.cs` in Entity Framework 6](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Core/Objects/EntityFunctions.cs)

Actually, if you use Entity Framework 6, I would recommend removing all and any references to `System.Data.Entity` - in order to avoid any future confusion and mistake.

Comment: Thanks, +1 this link has helped me to solve my problem. One thing is missing: Now is called in EF 6 DbFunctions.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're getting this error is that by design Linq to Entities converts all expression to server query. So it does not know how to translate `DiffDays` to SQL. Try to omit this method and rewrite expression.

---

*UPDATE:*

[`EntityFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx) are Canonical functions so you can [use them in Linq to Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456873.aspx). So the only reasonable explanation is in EF *Alhpa* version.

Comment: it's not a 'custom method' but part of Entity Framework utility functions to construct custom LINQ queries than **could** be translated into store expressions (SQL)

Comment: This answer doesn't really help the OP in my opinion, your just pointing out what the OP already knows as they have stated it "*works completely fine in Console app*".

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by changing all my EntityFunctions.TruncateTime to DbFunctions.TruncateTime and the error went away after examining various using statements and removing all of those that referenced System.Data.