# Get total days (int) between DateTime.Now and a certain DateTime

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

How can I get the total days as int between DateTime.Now and a specific DateTime? Can this be done using LINQ?

Comment: Why should you use LINQ? LINQ is mainly a framework to deal with (massive) data processing.

Comment: You need to be clearer about this - are you only interested in *local* times? Or a particular time zone? What about partial days? There are *simple* approaches to this - but the *correct* approach will need you to specify your requirements more carefully. You might also then want to use Noda Time (http://nodatime.org)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can simply calculate the difference using the following method:

```
DateTime a = ;//some datetime
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan ts = now-a;
int days = Math.Abs(ts.Days);
```

Comment: looks like `Days` is just the change, not the total, `TotalDays` should be used, also notice that `TotalDays` can be minus, so if the OP asks for the **difference**, I think he wants some positive value and hence we should use `Math.Abs` plus some (int) casting to get the last result.

Comment: Not really, the difference between `Days` and `TotalDays` is that `TotalDays` is a double describing the fraction part as well. Point taken with the difference.

Comment: I dont see this specified in the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days.aspx. Furthermore `TimeSpan` is not aware of the original dates anymore.

Comment: Well, it's obviously you're right, I don't work with TimeSpan much.

Comment: @KingKing you are correct for `Hours` vs `TotalHours` and the other similar parings, but for `Days` it does not matter if you don't care about the fractional part of the days.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks for the info, it's also true for `Minutes`. I think day is not treated the same way with hour and minute because a month does not always contain 30 days, it depends on the year and month. but a day always contains 24 hours and an hour always contains 60 minutes.

Answer (score 10):

Simply subtract two `DateTime`s from each other, into a `TimeSpan`, and get the `TotalDays` component from it.

```
TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now - OtherDateTime
int days = (int)Math.Abs(Math.Round(diff.TotalDays));
```

It is rounded to remove the fraction caused by the hours/minutes/seconds, and the absolute value is given so you get the exact change.

Comment: `TotalDays` is a `double`, describing both the integer (full days) and fraction (remainder) part. I think you will at least have to convert it to an integer.

Comment: @CommuSoft: Fixed, Whoops :)

Comment: You should use Math.Floor instead of Math.Round because it has to be full days. We don't want to round 2.9 day to 3 but we want to get 2 full days and don't care about the rest.

Answer (score 1):

In **Linq2Object**:

```
DateTime.Now.Subtract(yourDateTime).TotalDays
```

In **Linq2Entites**:

```
     EntityFunctions.DiffDays(DateTime.Now, yourDateTime)
```

Comment: What kind of `LINQ-to-Object` are you using? =))

Comment: `.Subtract()` is a normal method on `DateTime` and is not Linq2Objects.

Comment: @KingKing I meant Linq2Objecs is not supported when used in Linq2Entities

Comment: I still don't see why LINQ should be used... Simply using operator overloading is way easier.

Comment: @KingKing If two values of the type of DateTime are stored in a DB, can you STILL use that overloading???

Comment: @Alireza what **overloading** do you mention here?

Comment: @KingKing Sorry. My mistake. No overload. I didn't get your word **operator** overloading. Anyway, do you think subtracting two DateTime columns in Linq2Entities actually works?

Comment: @Alireza of course it doesn't work, we have to use some kind of special function as in your post.

Comment: @KingKing All the thing I wanted to emphasis was this difference. Perhaps I wasn't good enough to clear that

Comment: This is no longer valid - as of EF6, the type path is now `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions`. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538925/linq-entityfunctions-in-asp-net-mvc)