# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method EntityFunctions.DiffMonths

Tags: linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I am trying to execute Linq query in using EntityFramework and get error

```
System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] DiffMonths(System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime], System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

The code

```
public bool FreeConversionExceeded(string ip)
    {
        var count = _statisticRepository.GetAll().Count(p => p.Ip == ip && EntityFunctions.DiffMonths(DateTime.UtcNow, p.DateStamp) == 0);
        return count > 200;
    }


public IQueryable<Statistic> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.Statistic;
    }
```

I just do not understand why `EntityFunctions.DiffMonths` is not working. From help file "`This function is translated to a corresponding function in the database.`", so it should work?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this, it works with `DateTime` and `DateTime?` columns.

Comment: I also do not understand why it is not working. It worked fine in my previous project and I can't find the reason for that!

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact problem. The solution was posted here [LINQ + EntityFunctions in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538925/linq-entityfunctions-in-asp-net-mvc).

The problem is that you may reference EntityFunctions from `System.Data.Objects`. If you are using EntityFramework, try to reference to `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects`.

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
```

Btw, EntityFunctions is deprecated. Try to use DbFunctions instead.

```
using System.Data.Entity;
...
...
...
public bool FreeConversionExceeded(string ip)
{
    var count = _statisticRepository.GetAll().Count(p => p.Ip == ip && DbFunctions.DiffMonths(DateTime.UtcNow, p.DateStamp) == 0);
    return count > 200;
}
```

I know this answer is few years late.
But I hope this post could help someone facing a similar problem.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

you need Nullable not DateTime

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.diffmonths%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd382850%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand you answer. Could you show a example?